# Python parser xml nested element find by name

Tags: python, parsing

I have a nested XML to parser with Python. Example

```
<custom-objects xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customobject/2006-10-31">
<custom-object type-id="AbandonedBaskets" object-id="b4122d6090d1d6a3f8dafd34b0">
    <object-attribute attribute-id="basketJson">{"UUID":"b4122d6090d1d6a3f8dafd34b0"}</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="cnRelatedNo">1365</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="customerOwnerNo">702069175</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="lastModifiedBasketDate">2022-06-29T21:31:04.000+0000</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="natg_emailAlreadySent">true</object-attribute>
</custom-object>
```

I need to create a for to extract a elements attribute-id="basketJson" and  attribute-id="lastModifiedBasketDate" anyone can help us ? tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example `beautifulsoup` to parse the XML:

```py
xml_doc = """\
<custom-objects xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customobject/2006-10-31">
<custom-object type-id="AbandonedBaskets" object-id="b4122d6090d1d6a3f8dafd34b0">
    <object-attribute attribute-id="basketJson">{"UUID":"b4122d6090d1d6a3f8dafd34b0"}</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="cnRelatedNo">1365</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="customerOwnerNo">702069175</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="lastModifiedBasketDate">2022-06-29T21:31:04.000+0000</object-attribute>
    <object-attribute attribute-id="natg_emailAlreadySent">true</object-attribute>
</custom-object>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

for obj in soup.select("custom-object"):
    print("basketJson =", obj.select_one('[attribute-id="basketJson"]').text)
    print(
        "lastModifiedBasketDate =",
        obj.select_one('[attribute-id="lastModifiedBasketDate"]').text,
    )
```

Prints:

```
basketJson = {"UUID":"b4122d6090d1d6a3f8dafd34b0"}
lastModifiedBasketDate = 2022-06-29T21:31:04.000+0000
```